# How to check at compile time if type is polymorhic

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I have template function. In the template function I am using dynamic_cast on the template argument. But since you can't use dynamic_cast on non polymorphic type, I want to check if type is polymorphic ( has at least one virtual function ) at compile time, and if type is not polymorphic I will skip using dynamic_cast. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_polymorphic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic):

```
struct Foo {};

std::cout << std::is_polymorphic<Foo>::value << std::endl;
```

You can use this in combination with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to use different code depending on its value.

Answer (score 2):

Another way compared to @juanchopanza

```
template<class T>
struct IsPolymorphic
{
    struct Derived : T {
        virtual ~Derived();
    };
    enum  { value = sizeof(Derived)==sizeof(T) };
};

class PolyBase {
public:   
    virtual ~PolyBase(){}
};

class NPolyBase {
public:
    ~NPolyBase(){}
};

void ff()
{
    std::cout << IsPolymorphic<PolyBase >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsPolymorphic<NPolyBase>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: can you explain about the mechanism how it works. I don't really understand it

Comment: pointer to virtual table takes memory, so, sizeof(NPolyBase) will be less then sizeof(Derived) from it, because Derived will have pointer to virtual table, NPoly will not.
So, this way you will always check if checking class don't have virtual methods.

Comment: I will also add, that C++ Standart don't define how compiler have to manage virtual table, so, class body may not have pointer to virtual table inside it in some rare compilers. Still, GCC and msvc have such pointers inside class, so, such check will work, but that is not good to use such undeclared behaviour.

Comment: In addition, your trait will fail with `final` classes.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you explain, I don't understand why it will fail. What you mean by final classes?

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you for such new feature of C++11, I didn't knew before :-) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: @user152508: I mean something like `struct D final : B {};` (see the above link provided).